# Remove/Disable all code added by Tumblr?

Tags: javascript, html, tumblr

So Tumblr adds a whole bunch of iframes and javascript into my Tumblr.

It makes my blog slow and personally, I don't care about analytics, social media or user interaction like comments and stuff.

I know that for Blogger, it is possible to remove the widget.js but is it possible for Tumblr? I would like to make my markup as close to the one I made in the html editor as possible.

**Edit:**

Okay, specifically I'm concerned about the part of the code enclosed within the `<!-- BEGIN TUMBLR CODE -->Blah Blah<!-- END TUMBLR CODE -->.`
It runs a lot of javascript there while makes loading it slow.

Example:
view-source:http://placeholder9000.tumblr.com/

If removing the code is not an option, maybe perhaps disabling it? have it enclosed in a comment tag?

Personally, I figure since my code has priority, maybe a javascript to prevent the page from executing any other javascript?

Comment: These iframes you wish to remove, have you checked to see if it's in the terms of use? They give you a free web page under the agreement you let them display information on each page?

Comment: This is a very broad statement and too much to cover in just one question. Please be specific, How can I remove comments from my Tumblr theme? Have you looked at the theme docs: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes